# Create EF Core DBContext in controller for multi-threading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In one of my controllers, I have an async method that has to make a few db calls simultaneously, so I set it up like this:

```
public xxxController(IConfiguration configuration, xxxContext xxxContext, xxx2Context xxx2Context)
   : base(xxxContext)
```

I store the contexts that are injected. In the particular method:

```
var v = await Task.WhenAll(... )
```

Inside of the WhenAll, I need to use the xxxContext for each item, so I get the non-thread safe exception.

What is the correct way to create a new DbContext? Right now I'm doing:

```
var v = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<xxxContext>();   
v.UseSqlServer(_xxxContext.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString);    
xxContext e = new xxContext(v.Options);
```

So I'm getting the connection string from the existing context that was injected and use that to create a new one.

The connection strings are stored in appSettings.json. In the "ConnectionStrings" section.

Is there a cleaner way to create the contexts for multi-threading?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I created something like factory class which can provide context per call. For your case it can be

```
public class AppDependencyResolver
{
    private static AppDependencyResolver _resolver;

    public static AppDependencyResolver Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (_resolver == null)
                throw new Exception("AppDependencyResolver not initialized. You should initialize it in Startup class");
            return _resolver;
        }
    }

    public static void Init(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _resolver = new AppDependencyResolver(services);
    }

    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    private AppDependencyResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public xxxContext CreatexxxContextinCurrentThread()
    {
        var scopeResolver = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope();
        return scopeResolver.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<xxxContext>();
    }
}
```

Than you should call `Init` method in Startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    AppDependencyResolver.Init(app.ApplicationServices);
    //other configure code
}
```

You can look my approach for this on [github](https://github.com/YuriyPavlishin/MvcAppBaseCore/blob/master/src/BaseApp.Web/Code/Infrastructure/AppDependencyResolver.cs)

Comment: do I need to call `CreatexxxContextinCurrentThread()` anywhere?

Comment: You need to call it only in thread which you created by yourself. Otherwise it is better  to use standard resolve approach. (and do not forget to dispose scopeResolver. I did not mention it in answer for simplicity reason)

Answer (score -1):

I afraid you executing your asynchronous methods in this way

```
var task = Task.Run(() => MyAsynchronosMethod());
```

`DbContext` operations are Input-Output operations you don't need to execute them on different thread to work "simultaneously". You can get it working without new threads.

```
public MyController(IConfiguration configuration, AContext aContext, BContext bContext)
    : base(aContext)
{ 
    _aContext = aContext;
    _bContext = bContext;
}

public Task<IActionResult> GetSomething(int id)
{
    var customerTask = aContext.Customers
                                     .FirstOrDefaultAsync(customer => customer.Id == id);
    var sellerTask = aContext.Sellers
                                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync(seller => seller.CustomerId == id);
    var ordersTask = bContext.Orders
                                   .Where(order => order.CustomerId == id)
                                   .ToListAsync();
    var invoicesTask = bContext.Invoices
                                     .Where(invoice => invoice.CustomerId == id)
                                     .ToListAsync();
    var allTasks = new[] { customerTask, sellerTask, ordersTask, invoicesTask};
    await Task.WhenAll(allTasks);

    // Do stuff with result of completed tasks

    Return OK(calculatedResult);
}
```

In method above you will send all queries almost simultaneously without waiting for response. You start waiting for responses only after all queries were send.
After all query results arrived you can process data - all operations will be executed on one thread.